CoreData Predicate for empty NSSet (One-to-Many relationship)
I have a CoreData entity called Item, which may or may not contain Properties. I would like to fetch all Items that have not yet been assigned any Properties.
extension Item {

    @nonobjc public class func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: Int
    @NSManaged public var link: String
    @NSManaged public var summary: String
    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var properties: NSSet?

    @objc(addPropertiesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToProperties(_ value: Properties)

    @objc(removePropertiesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromProperties(_ value: Properties)

    @objc(addProperties:)
    @NSManaged public func addToProperties(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeProperties:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromProperties(_ values: NSSet)

}

extension Properties {

    @nonobjc public class func createfetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Properties> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Properties>(entityName: "Properties")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var favourite: Bool
    @NSManaged public var item: Item

}

So far, I've tried setting an NSPredicate in two ways:
let request = Item.createFetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self.properties.count == 0") // 1
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self.properties == nil") // 2

Both attempts result in a crash with the following error message:
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600003b09ce0> , to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Can someone help me figure out how to format such a predicate, please?

Try @count = 0

If you meant "self.properties.count = 0", this, too, results in the same error message, I'm affraid.

I meant self.properties.@count = 0 (note the @ sign).

Brilliant! That worked. Thanks, mate! I'm not familiar with this notation - what does the @count actuall mean, please?

See Using Collection Operators
